# manual reload causes error while binding the binding context

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

While implementing a basic controller I ran into an unexpected error. The code below works fine (meaning the bindingContext is created) when the user navigates to the view. If the user reloads the page manually the context stays undefined. I debugged the code and the model is the same object in both scenarios. For now I added a manual check to prevent errors. The Question is: **Why is no binding Context created?**

Cheers

```
sap.ui.define([
    "de/nordakademie/bookatrip/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/m/MessageToast"],
function (BaseController, History, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";
    return BaseController.extend("de.nordakademie.bookatrip.controller.BaseDetail", {
        onInit: function () {
            this._getRouter()
                .getRoute("detail")
                .attachPatternMatched(this._onDetailRouteMatched, this);
        },
        _onDetailRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
            const oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
            const oView = this.getView();
            const i18n = this.getI18nBundle();
            const oContext = oView
                .getModel("trip")
                .createBindingContext("/" + oArgs.path);
            /**
             * in case of manual browser reload, binding the context will fail (why?)
             * to prevent unexpected errors on tis view, the user will be navigated to
             * previous page
             */
            if (oContext) {
                oView.setBindingContext(oContext, "trip");
            } else {
                MessageToast.show(i18n.getText("detail.binding.navback"),
                    {closeOnBrowserNavigation: false});
                this.onNavButtonPress()
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you're manually creating a BindingContext? Normally we use the [bindElement](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/bindElement) method to bind the View.

When you use the bindElement method, the framework takes care of reusing the existing bindings if the page is reloaded (not really a full reload, but rather a re-match of the same route).

Try doing it like this instead:

```
    _onDetailRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
        const oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
        const oView = this.getView();
        const i18n = this.getI18nBundle();

        oView.bindElement({
            model: "trip",
            path: "/" + oArgs.path
        });
    }
```

Obs: You can also bind it using the model name as part of the path, like this:

```
        oView.bindElement("{trip>/" + oArgs.path + "}");
```